# parsing soap response using Cypress

Tags: soap, cypress

Facing issues while parsing this response using cypress,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
          
                    <p385:summaryOutputArray xmlns:p385="http://dataobject.simulation.com">
                        <p385:userName>MS</p385:userName>
                        
                    </p385:summaryOutputArray>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Using Cypress How to read userName TAG? I can see in the log that whole xml is printed but can't get to the particular tag. Also, while using the function to get to the particular tag to get the value, I am getting null property

Firstly I used this. This is giving error. property reading null

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(quoteResp, 'text/xml');
cy.log('xmlDOM ' + quoteResp.);
cy.wrap(Cypress.$(quoteResp)).then(quoteResp => {
const txt  = quoteResp.filter('Body').find('p385:userName').text();

 cy.log('value:' + txt);
 });
```

Using this I can see the whole response in logs

```
then(quoteResp => {cy.log('xmlDOM ' + quoteResp.body);
```

Comment: Add your code that you tried along with the error messages that you got.

Comment: Thanks for bring that into attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to wrap the response, just query the `xmlDOM` like this

```js
const xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(quoteResp, 'application/xml');
const userName = xmlDOM.querySelector('userName').textContent

expect(userName).to.eq('MS')
```

Comment: I used this it throws me  "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')"
This is the code. 


.then(quoteResp => {

                            const parser = new DOMParser();

                            const xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(quoteResp, 'application/xml');

                            const userName = xmlDOM.querySelector('userName').textContent;
                            cy.log('xmlDOM ' + userName);

Comment: I just ran your code and it works (using XML you show above). Only answer is the XML in `quoteResp` is not the same.

Comment: Now its working. Thanks for the help. I have one more question.

 After parsing the response. I have to replace that response into the next request call. How can we do that?